# Aggregation with GROUP BY using AspNet Core OData and Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, entity-framework-core, linq2db

Simple OData aggregation fails on Entity Framework Core (SQL Sever) and Asp.Net Core:

```
odata/file?$apply=groupby((FileType))
```

Due to inability to translate used GroupBy LINQ expression warning is issued:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Warning: The LINQ expression 'GroupBy(new GroupByWrapper() {GroupByContainer = new LastInChain() {Name = "FileType", Value = [$it].FileType}}, [$it])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

And then exception is thrown:

```
system.security.verificationexception operation could destabilize the runtime
```

most relevant stack:

```
at lambda_method(Closure , File )
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
```

Used NuGet packages versions:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.0.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.1
- Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.2

Repo showing the issue: https://github.com/xmichaelx/ODataGroupByTest

Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1578

I'm not sure where the issue lies, whether EF Core should be able to convert LINQ query to valid SQL or OData generates difficult to convert GroupBy expression. Until it's sorted out I'm looking for some workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq2Db extensions to EF Core as workaround.

After adding NuGet packages:

- linq2db 2.2.0
- linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore 1.0.1

And changing from

```
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_db.Files);
    }
```

to

```
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_db.Files.ToLinqToDB());
    }
```

everything works.

Branch with fix: https://github.com/xmichaelx/ODataGroupByTest/tree/issue-workaround
linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore : https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore

EDIT: sum, avg, min, max works, countdistinct does not work

Comment: do you know if this issue has been fixed in later versions?

Answer (score -1):

I used LinqToDb and this resolves aggregate issue.
Steps:

1. Install package : Linq2Db.EntityFrameworkCore
2. In your data provider use : Using LinqToDb.Entityframeworkcore
3. In your db query add - ToLinqToDb();

This resolves the aggregate issue.
Limitations observed : $filter(Contains) with aggregate do not work and if you are using pagination $top too wont work.